# How to solve 'result cannot be resolved to a variable' error in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I want to apply a sequencing logic code on the Select Output block, but when I build the model it becomes error and said 'result cannot be resolved to a variable'[code on anylogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUOCQ.png)

I want to apply the sequencing method by applying those code on the select output block. I want the output can return the
-Product sequencing
-Total flow time
-Total tardiness
-Average tardiness
-Number of tardy jobs

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no `result` in your agent type. Either add it to the agent or navigate via code to where `result` "lives", such as `main.result` or `mySubAgent.get(0).result`.

You need to understand your model hierarchy and how to navigate it, see https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to